# Change InnerHTML based on anchor click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a little new to Web Development so I was hoping someone could answer this for me.

I'm building a prototype for a "Web Messenger" similar to Facebook messenger. I have a sidebar that I populate with a UL of anchor tags when the window loads and it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKteI.jpg). Here is the code for it

```
var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
var newUL = document.createElement('ul');
newUL.id = 'menu-content';
newUL.className = 'menu-content collapse out';

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  var newLI = document.createElement('li');
  var newA = document.createElement('a');
  newA.id = 'chat' + i;
  newA.setAttribute('href', "#");
  newA.innerHTML = "Chat" + (i + 1);
  newLI.appendChild(newA);
  newUL.appendChild(newLI);
}

toAdd.appendChild(newUL)
document.getElementById("menu-list").appendChild(toAdd);
```

I also have a Div at the top of the page which will display some details about the current chat, but for the time being will simply display the name of the chat, same as on the anchor tags.

Now based on another StackOverflow post the correct way to call a JS function from an anchor tag is

```
var c0 = document.getElementById("chat0");

//Set code to run when the link is clicked
// by assigning a function to "onclick"
c0.onclick = function(id) {
  //Change Title Name here
  //Do other stuff in the future
  return false;
}
```

However I could have 20+ chats on the sidebar at any one time, so this seems like a lot of repetitive code to write.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your chats a general class instead example `chat` then attach the click event to all the chat's in the same time using `.getElementsByClassName()`.

So you could add className just after `newA.id` :

```
newA.id = 'chat' + i;
newA.className = 'chat';
```

Then attach the click event :

```
var chats = document.getElementsByClassName('chat');

for (var i=0; i < chats.length; i++) {
    chats[i].addEventListener('click', chatClick, false);
}

function chatClick(){
    //chat is clicked
    //The 'this' object here refer to clicked element
}
```

You could use `.addEventListener()` instead of onclick.

**NOTE :** You can attach the `click` event directly after node creation :

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var newLI = document.createElement('li');
    var newA = document.createElement('a');
    newA.id = 'chat' + i;
    newA.setAttribute('href', "#");
    newA.innerHTML = "Chat" + (i + 1);
    newA.addEventListener('click', chatClick, false); //Attach click event HERE
    newLI.appendChild(newA);
    newUL.appendChild(newLI);
  }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added `newA.addEventListener('click', chatClick)` inside the creation for loop and I've also added `function chatClick(){console.log("test");}` to the JS file, but when I click on the a tags nothing is displayed in the console? Did I miss something?

Comment: Try to add the `, false` at the end of `addEventListener`, check my update.

Answer (score 0):

Yap sure. You can give them all a class and after load just use a simple `jQuery` code to bind onclick for all of them:

```
 $('a.className').click(function() {
     // Your code here
 });
```

Now if the a tags are added after execution of the code you just simply need to call this again or bind to those elements manually.